# javascript function does not work when two input field values are entered

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

When I run this and click submit, it only functions if I do not enter both values into the form.  If I enter just one field or no data, then it returns as expected but when I enter both town and email, the userText flashes on the screen then disappears.  What am I missing??  Thanks for any help....

```
    <html>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label>What's Your Home Town?
        <input type="text" id="town" size="40" maxlength="60" required>
    </label>    
    <label>Email Address?
        <input type="email" id="email" size="40" maxlength="60" required>
        </label>
    <label>Submit
    </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
  </fieldset>
        <p id = "text"></p>

</form>

<script>



        function validateForm() {
            var userTown = document.getElementById('town').value;
            var userEmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var userText = userTown +'\'s a Great Town!' + ' click this link to email someone who cares ' + userEmail;
            //alert(userText + ' Follow This Link to Send an Email to Someone who Cares ' + userEmail);
           document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=userText;    

        }

        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: well a submit button submits so I am not surprised....

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `submit` type button in the form so form is submitted. Changing it to `button` type will solve your problem

```js
function validateForm() {
  var userTown = document.getElementById('town').value;
  var userEmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var userText = userTown + '\'s a Great Town!' + ' click this link to email someone who cares <a href="mailto' + userEmail +'">' + userEmail +'</a>';
  //alert(userText + ' Follow This Link to Send an Email to Someone who Cares ' + userEmail);
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = userText;

}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label>What's Your Home Town?
        <input type="text" id="town" size="40" maxlength="60" required>
    </label>
    <label>Email Address?
        <input type="email" id="email" size="40" maxlength="60" required>
        </label>
    <label>Submit
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
  </fieldset>
  <p id="text"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you..How can i get the userEmail to display as a hyperlink?

Comment: @Corina update my answer. Do accept and upvote if it helped :)

Comment: how do i Accept and upvote?   I do not see either option :(

Comment: to accept just click on the tick mark in front of my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer